# Managing Uploaded File Validation using Servlet

Tags: file, servlets, time, process, upload

I have the below requirement

A large text file around 10Mb to 25Mb (With 50,000 to 100,000 lines of data) is uploaded into the web application. I have to validate the file line by line and write the output to another location and then display a message to the user.
        The App Server is WebLogic and its is accessed through Web Server through Apache Bridge. Apache Bridge times out pretty quickly during the upload + processing activity. Is there any way to solve this issue without changing the timeout of the  Apache Bridge

What is best possible solution ? Below are my current thoughts.

**Soln 1**     Upload the file and return back to the page. Then trigger a Ajax to run the validation in a separate thread and check its status through further Ajax requests.
**Soln 2**. Use sc_partial_content(206) http Code to keep the connection alive.